# New B550 asrock steel legend ethernet 2.5G not working or being detected

Tags: networking, ethernet

i have built a new pc recently, however the 2.5G isn't being picked up by elementary or any ubuntu based distro, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here. I built a new computer a few days ago using another B550 chipset motherboard. My Gigabyte B550 Aorus Pro V2 also has the Realtek 2.5GbE LAN. I tried Hera 5.1.7 (20200814 build) and did not recognise the network adapter on boot.

I did the steps below and I managed to make it recognise the 2.5GbE controller.

From [Realtek official page](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) download the [r8125 linux driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/directly-download?downloadid=95f1076134d28cfcebcb49fc65a6811e).
Extract and copy the r8125 driver to your computer with the B550 motherboard.

Install `make` and `gcc` packages from the bootable Elementary USB by issuing the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install make gcc
```

After the packages are installed, open a terminal to the directory that contains the extracted drivers and give the command:

```
$ sudo ./autorun.sh
```

If everything went well, the drivers should be installed successfully. You can check if the driver is loaded by using the following:

```
$ lsmod | grep r8125
```

In my case the output was:

```
r8125        151552    0
```

If everything went well, at this point you should have access to the Internet. If not, try to check the `README` file in the driver's directory for extra guidance.